How many question marks should be in a compound question sentence?
I have a compound question in the following format:

What Do Students Learn and What are They Doing About it?

Should it contain two question marks as follows:

What Do Students Learn? and What are They Doing About it?


You can only ever one question in a sentence, at the end. A sentence is ended by a period, exclamation mark, or question mark.

A single question mark, at the end. You may put a comma before "and", or one could split it into two sentences (questions) each with a question mark.
Also, capital letters should only be at the start of the sentence (unless this is a title, in which case sentence grammar isn't required)

But one could split it into two sentences (questions): What do students learn? And what are they doing about it.

@PaulTanenbaum What do students learn? And what are they doing about it ? [without the space]

The capitalization in the question suggests that it is a title. In which case two sentences might read a bit better, in my opinion.
